# I get resource # 7 in database when uploading image

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to resize an image when uploading it using php to my database, but whenever I try to fetch the data I uploaded, my database base says `resource id #7`.

The image I upload, uploads to my folder with the resize and original image but I can't seem to fetch the resized image back. Below is the code I use to upload, resize and store the image.

Thank you!

```
$fileuploaddetected = isset($_FILES['file']) && ($_FILES['file']['error'] === 0);
$uploaderrordetected = isset($_FILES['file']) && ($_FILES['file']['error'] > 0);

if ($fileuploaddetected) {
    if (is_array($_FILES)) {
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $sourceProperties = getimagesize($file);
        $fileNewName = time();
        $folderPath = "uploads/";
        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $imageType = $sourceProperties[2];

        switch ($imageType) {
            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                $imageResourceId = imagecreatefrompng($file);
                $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId, $sourceProperties[0], $sourceProperties[1]);
                imagepng($targetLayer, $folderPath . $fileNewName . "_thump." . $ext);
                break;
            case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                $imageResourceId = imagecreatefromgif($file);
                $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId, $sourceProperties[0], $sourceProperties[1]);
                imagegif($targetLayer, $folderPath . $fileNewName . "_thump." . $ext);
                break;
            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                $imageResourceId = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId, $sourceProperties[0], $sourceProperties[1]);
                imagejpeg($targetLayer, $folderPath . $fileNewName . "_thump." . $ext);
                break;
            default:
                echo "Invalid Image type.";
                exit;
                break;
        }
        move_uploaded_file($file, $folderPath . $fileNewName . "." . $ext);
    }
}

function imageResize($imageResourceId, $width, $height) {
    $targetWidth = 300;
    $targetHeight = 300;
    $targetLayer = imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth, $targetHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($targetLayer, $imageResourceId, 0, 0, 0, 0, $targetWidth, $targetHeight, $width, $height);
    return $targetLayer;
}


$title = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'title', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$content = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'content', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);

$error = true;

if (!empty($title) && !empty($content)) {
    $userid = $_SESSION['id'];
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = :id";
    $statement2 = $db->prepare($query2);
    $statement2->bindValue(':id', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement2->execute();
    $postys = $statement2->fetch();

    $userrname = $postys['username'];

    if ($fileuploaddetected) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO blog (title, content, picurl, userid, username) VALUES (:title, :content, :picurl, :userid, :username)";
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(':title', $title);
        $statement->bindValue(':content', $content);
        $statement->bindValue(':picurl', $targetLayer);
        $statement->bindValue(':userid', $userid);
        $statement->bindValue(':username', $userrname);
        $statement->execute();

        $blog = $statement->fetchAll();

        $error = false;
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a clear error description. And what is your programming question about that error description? I somehow can imagine that you're disappointed the code produces unexpected results, but I must admit I have problems to locate the place in the code where you do that output so the question is not really clear to me.

Comment: sorry about that. My question is how to i grab the resize image i uploaded to insert it to my database

Comment: How do you want to insert it into the database? As a string that contains the absolute path to the image file or as the binary data of the image or how?

Comment: i want to insert is as a string the contains the resized image path

Comment: And can you show the part of the code that is related to inserting the string that contains the resized image path into the database? I have problems to find it in your question.